# Cron Job in WIndows on WampServer

Tags: php, windows, cron, wamp, wampserver

I am new about Cron Job. I am creating a task that a Auto-Email will be send based on a condition.
I am using WampServer. and a number of PHP files are there. Database is mysql. Somebody tell me, cron job is not working on window but i dont know. 
Please anyone suggest me, Is cron job possible in windows for wamp server. If yes, How can i implement it? any example or any library?

Thank a lot for your important timing.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you'll need to use the [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IE/windows7/schedule-a-task). Windows does not have cron.